# Robotium/Android JUnit: How to scroll views inside the Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, junit, scrollview, navigation-drawer, robotium

My application has a ScrollView inside a Navigation Drawer. I'm trying to perform a click using Solo's clickOnText on a text in the ScrollView. However, the said text is not visible on screen, that is, I must perform a scroll on Drawer's ScrollView in order to the text becomes visible and I can perform the click.

I tried to use mSolo.scrollToBottom(); but it did not work, the ScrollView remains still and JUnit keeps saying that my text is not found.

Thank you in advance for your replies!

Comment: Have you solved this issue??

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the text dynamically to the TextView, try to call textView.requestLayout() before you do anything. This will cause the TextView to be re-drawn so you might get your text visible.

Does this help?

Comment: I'm not adding the text dynamically. If I use clickOnText with a similar text that is **drawn on screen** in the ScrollView inside the Drawer, the click is performed successfully.